# SugarCRM save database data to file

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

Is there any way I can save the data of a specific table of the sugarcrm database into a doc file ?

I have a custom module with username,some notes and date. I want to write this into the database and into a file as well.

Its not just a php file. I want to use logic hooks and write the code. I want to use the logic hooks to access database and then write the data into the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple google search of "write to file with php" would answer this question for you.

Comment: I can write with php, my question is if it is possible in sugarcrm in my custom module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving as a DOC file probably isn't the best idea, since it is primarily used for formatting information.  A standard .txt file is usually what you would use for such a process.

With that said, there isn't any methods built into sugar that will let you do this.  You will need to build the capability into the module.

What exactly are you attempting to accomplish?  There is a very powerful auditing tool set, which is good for seeing revisions to a module object.  If you are just wanting to monitor changes to the table, you can setup logging for that table/database inside of SQL.

+++Ok, if you are just looking to write to a file after saves, follow the instructions at: http://cheleguanaco.blogspot.com/2009/06/simple-sugarcrm-logic-hook-example.html for a quick how-to on getting the logic hooks working.  You are going to want to make a php file that simply uses the data passed to it via the bean class, and either writes to the file directly from the data within bean, or uses the bean->id parameter to do a SQL query and write to the file from that data.

Also, is this a DOC file that is going to be immediately generated and then destroyed at the end of the transaction? Or is it more of a log file that will be persistent?

++++That is simple enough then
Where you have the Query right now, replace it with:

```
$file = fopen($pathAndNameOfFile, 'a+') or die('Could not open file.');
$query = "SELECT * FROM data_base.table";
$result = $bean->db->query($query,true);
$dbRowData = $bean->db->mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$printedArray = print_r($dbRowData);     
fwrite($file, $printedArray) or die('Could not write to file.');
fclose($file);
```

*A quick note, you might need to set permissions in order to be able to read/write to the file, but those are specific to the machine type, so if you encounter errors with either do a search for setting permissions for your particular server type.

**Also, 'SELECT * FROM database.table' is going to return ALL of the rows in the entire table.  This will generate a very large file, and be a performance hindrance as the table grows.  You should use the bean class to update the last saved tuple:

```
$file = fopen($pathAndNameOfFile, 'a+') or die('Could not open file.');
$query = "SELECT * FROM data_base.table WHERE id = '".$focus->id."';";
$result = $bean->db->query($query,true);
$dbRowData = $bean->db->mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$printedArray = print_r($dbRowData);     
fwrite($file, $printedArray) or die('Could not write to file.');
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I do not want to monitor the changes. I just want to save them in the doc file. It is easier to do it with just php and MySQL. Adding sugarcrm to the equation makes it hard. I was looking at the logic_hooks of the sugarcrm. There is a possibility to make sql query. I can get the data just like in the php, but I want to know what can be after that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked the blog already, I know how to write a logic hooks code.I wrote a simple code to read the data          $query = "SELECT * FROM `data_base'\n";
$result = $bean->db->query($query,true); 
$row = $bean->db->fetchrow($result);     I want to write the data into a file now. How do I do it. Is it possible to do with a code? The document is like the log file, it will be persistent.

Comment: Like you said, How do I write data passed by the bean class to the doc file. I am fairly new to sugarcrm and PHP in that matter. I am still learning.

Comment: Thank you. So I add the code in the php file in the same class with the other code.

Comment: Add the code wherever you are performing the database query.  You should be able to take the data collected in the $row variable, and plug it in where I used $dbRowData in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can export/dump mysql databases into SQL files using mysqldump

```
mysqldump -u userName -p databaseName tableName > fileName.sql
```

Comment: no I want to use logic hooks in sugarcrm for my custom module and save the data as a doc file not as a .sql file